# Unknown Source Java 10

Tags: java, java-stream

I am getting an error while running following code:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Harry");
    list.add("Marry");
    list.add(null);
    list.add("Larry");

    list.removeIf(e -> e.startsWith("H"));
    list.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

Getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at test/test.TestClass.lambda$0(TestClass.java:14)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(Unknown Source)
at test/test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:14)
```

Why I am getting the unknow source error, it  works fine if I provide following lambda:

```
list.removeIf(e -> e == null);
```

Comment: Hey  var list = new ArrayList<String>(); is this correct??

Comment: `.startsWith` doesn't work with `null` string. so you need to put condition there.

Comment: @NitinBisht yes it is correct from Java 10

Comment: the `Unknown Source` only means that there are no source files attached, i.e. the trace cannot determine which line (in a `.java` file) caused this `Exception`. The actual `Excpetion` is a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`null.startsWith("H")` returns `NullPointerException` instead you have to check if the value is null or not then use `startsWith`:

```
list.removeIf(e -> e != null && e.startsWith("H"));
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 4):

One of your entries is `null` and `e.startsWith("H")` gives a `NullPointerException`

```
list.removeIf(e -> e != null && e.startsWith("H"));
```

Answer (score 2):

it works when you perform:

```
list.removeIf(e -> e == null);
```

because you're explicitly saying "remove all null elements", so there is no chance of `NullPointerException` here.

whereas:

```
 list.removeIf(e -> e.startsWith("H"));
```

is saying "remove all elements that start with 'H' " but if `e` is null then you're doomed as it will yield a `NullPointerException`.

Instead, check if it's not null prior to checking whether it starts with "Hi" or not.

```
list.removeIf(e -> e != null && e.startsWith("H"));
```